# jQuery: How to reset a dropdown field after using detach function

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to hide certain options in my dropdown field.

Was banging my head over why, when I click on the first radio button, it works, but won't work for the others, then realized I need to reset the drop-down to its original options just after clicking another radio button.

My app has a radio-button group, you click on that group of several radios and based on the value of the radio-button, one of the IF statements below runs.

How do I reset a dropdown field to it's original or complete contents after using the detach function?

I've tried these, but they do not work:

```
$('#3547').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected'); 
document.getElementById('3547').selectedIndex = 0; 
document.getElementById('3547').reset();
```

**Code:**

```
var oldoptions = []; 
 if (typeVal == "Art")
         {      
             $('fieldset#section-417').show();
 thisval = 'Art -';
$("#3547").append(oldoptions);  
    oldoptions = $("#3547 option:not(:contains(" + thisval + "))").detach();
}
 if (typeVal == "Chrome")
         {      
             $('fieldset#section-417').show();
 thisval = 'Chrome -';
$("#3547").append(oldoptions);  
    oldoptions = $("#3547 option:not(:contains(" + thisval + "))").detach();
}
 if (typeVal == "Web")
         {      
             $('fieldset#section-417').show();
 thisval = 'Web -';
$("#3547").append(oldoptions);  
    oldoptions = $("#3547 option:not(:contains(" + thisval + "))").detach();
}
```

**re-clarification of functionality needed:**

I want to restore all the options that were originally in the dropdown before I filtered some out, so for ex: on load, the dropdown contains 12 options. When the 'ART' radio is checked, then only 4 items are displayed in the dropdown.  When I click on another radio button "Chrome" for example, I want the original 12 options restored to the dropdown, so the filter code can run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the surrounding code, but from this snippet you seem to always assign an empty array to `oldoptions` and then append it to the select (i.e. you're actually appending nothing).

Comment: Hi Aioros: I clear our oldOptions, assign it an array, then pass "$("#3547 option:not(:contains(" + thisval + "))").detach();" to it.  I think it's only "empty" just after the click. and remember it works with which ever radio i clicked first.  It's the subsequent clicks that do not work.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm seeing it wrong, but you do the `oldoptions = $(whatever).detach()` after the `append()`. So isn't `oldoptions` always still an empty array when you try and append it?
The first one would work anyway, since there are no old options to restore.

Comment: I see what you are saying, so I switched the around, now the dropdown just displays all the options  oldoptions = $("#3547 option:not(:contains(" + thisval + "))").detach();
    $("#3547").append(oldoptions); ---The filtering is not working anymore.

Comment: Ok, that's actually my fault, I didn't explain my solution: it was absolutely right to append the old options and then `detach()` the unwanted ones. You only had to remove the `oldoptions = []`, and it should work, provided that `oldoptions` is a global variable (so that its value is kept between different calls of this code).

Answer (score 0):

To select an option you should use:

```
.attr('selected', true)
```

CSS IDs should not start with a number. Maybe thats confusing your browser, too.

Comment: Hi Tsunamis:  I don't want to select an option, I want to restore all the options that were originally in the dropdown before I filtered some out, so for ex: on load, the dropdown contains 12 options, when the 'ART' radio is checked, then only 4 items are displayed in the dropdown.  When I click on another radio button, I want the original 12 options restored to the dropdown, so the filter code can run again.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Maybe .attr('disabled', 'disabled') and .removeAttr('disabled') is a working solution for you. Then your options are not altered. Otherwise I would recommend storing the options and restoring them (i.e. with $('#id').data('original_options', data)) before a new filter applies.

Comment: Tsunamis remove and disable don't work with IE, which is what's causing the larger issue.  Let me your orig_opt suggestions.  Thank you.